# Why is my Rcpp code is much slower than glmnet's?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, lasso-regression

I edited the lasso code from [this](https://github.com/fditraglia/econ722/blob/master/RcppArmadillo/lasso_shooting.cpp) site to use it for multiple lambda values. 
I used lassoshooting package for one lambda value (this package works for one lambda value) and glmnet for multiple lambda values for comparison.

The coefficient estimates are different and this is expected because of standardization and scaling back to original scale. This is out of scope and not important here.

For one parameter case, lassoshooting is 1.5 times faster.

Both methods used all 100 lambda values in my code for multiple lambda case.  But glmnet is 7.5 times faster than my cpp code. Of course, I expected that glmnet was faster, but this amount seems too much. Is it normal or is my code wrong?

---

---

**EDIT**

I also attached `lshoot` function which calculates coefficient path in an R loop. This outperforms my cpp code too.

Can I improve my cpp code?

C++ code:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec softmax_cpp(const vec & x, const vec & y) {
  return sign(x) % max(abs(x) - y, zeros(x.n_elem));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat lasso(const mat & X, const vec & y, const vec & lambda,
           const double tol = 1e-7, const int max_iter = 10000){
  int p = X.n_cols; int lam = lambda.n_elem;
  mat XX = X.t() * X;
  vec Xy = X.t() * y;
  vec Xy2 = 2 * Xy;
  mat XX2 = 2 * XX;
  mat betas = zeros(p, lam); // to store the betas

  vec beta = zeros(p); // initial beta for each lambda

  bool converged = false;
  int iteration = 0;
  vec beta_prev, aj, cj;

  for(int l = 0; l < lam; l++){
    while (!converged && (iteration < max_iter)){

      beta_prev = beta;

      for (int j = 0; j < p; j++){
        aj = XX2(j,j);
        cj = Xy2(j) - dot(XX2.row(j), beta) + beta(j) * XX2(j,j);
        beta(j) = as_scalar(softmax_cpp(cj / aj, as_scalar(lambda(l)) / aj));
      }
      iteration = iteration + 1;
      converged =  norm(beta_prev - beta, 1) < tol;  
    }
    betas.col(l) = beta;
    iteration = 0;
    converged = false;
  }
  return betas;
}
```

R code:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(rbenchmark)
library(glmnet)
library(lassoshooting)

sourceCpp("LASSO.cpp")

library(ElemStatLearn)
X <- as.matrix(prostate[,-c(9,10)])
y <- as.matrix(prostate[,9])
lambda_one <- 0.1
benchmark(cpp=lasso(X,y,lambda_one),
          lassoshooting=lassoshooting(X,y,lambda_one)$coefficients,
          order="relative", replications=100)[,1:4]

################################################
lambda <- seq(0,10,len=100)

benchmark(cpp=lasso(X,y,lambda),
          glmn=coef(glmnet(X,y,lambda=lambda)),
          order="relative", replications=100)[,1:4]

    ####################################################
```

---

**EDIT**

```
lambda <- seq(0,10,len=100)

lshoot <- function(lambda){
  betas <- matrix(NA,8,100)
  for(l in 1:100){
    betas[, l] <- lassoshooting(X,y,lambda[l])$coefficients
  }
  return(betas)
}

benchmark(cpp=lasso(X,y,lambda),
          lassoshooting_loop=lshoot(lambda),
          order="relative", replications=300)[,1:4]
```

Results for one parameter case:

```
           test replications elapsed relative
2 lassoshooting          300    0.06      1.0
1           cpp          300    0.09      1.5
```

Results for multiple parameter case:

```
  test replications elapsed relative
2 glmn          300    0.70    1.000
1  cpp          300    5.24    7.486
```

Results for lassoshooting loop and cpp:

```
                test replications elapsed relative
2 lassoshooting_loop          300    4.06    1.000
1                cpp          300    6.38    1.571
```

Comment: did you enable optimisations when building your code?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I attached a comment under the answer below. thanks

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: Using Rcpp. Rcpp generates some functions in R. When I run this function in R, it compiles the code in C++ background.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341106/overriding-system-defaults-for-c-compilation-flags-from-r

Answer (score 4):

Package {glmnet} uses warm starts and special rules for discarding lots of predictors, which makes fitting the whole "regularization path" very fast.

See [their paper](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/strong.pdf).

Comment: This explains the situation. (+1)  I attached a new code for comparison of lassoshooting and cpp for multiple parameters case (see edits). But my cpp code is still bad. Is it normal too? Can I make edits to improve my cpp code?

Comment: @mert As mentioned by another commenter, you seem to be compiling the code without optimisations. If so, no wonder it’s slow. Modern C++ compilers rely *heavily* on optimisations being enabled.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm very new to C++ (via Rcpp). Maybe what you write is obvious but I don't know how to do it. Can you suggest me a reference to learn it?