# Is there a way to use/install reticulate/RcppTOML with an older version of C++/without C++17?

Tags: python, r, c++17, conda, reticulate

I am currently working on a project where I am attempting to run my R script remotely on a campus computer cluster. As such, I don't have sudo privileges and cannot change the R configuration file. I need to use reticulate, however, when I attempt to install reticulate, I receive the error `Error: C++17 standard requested but CXX17 is not defined`. This error occurs when R is attempting to install the RcppTOML packages (a reticulate dependency). When I open the configuration file, I see that C++14 is defined, but the C++17 line is just

```
C++17 =
```

I have tried to edit the config file, but do not have permissions. I can try to reach out to the server administrators, but it will likely take several days to hear back from them, and maybe longer for them to fix this problem.

Is there a way I can use reticulate with C++14 or is there a different way to fix this other than editing the config file?

I can use anaconda, so is there a way I can fix this by installing a new install of R with condo?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure how successful this would be, seeing as you can't use the 'standard' methods of configuring package compilation, but perhaps try specifying compiler flags using `R CMD INSTALL` from the command line, (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10935698/12957340/); for example, `R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="CXX17=path/to/bin/g++-13"` (or whatever you want to change)

Comment: Consider using Conda Forge for everything in the R installation. You don't need elevated privileges for Conda, and Conda Forge builds most of what people actually use. If there is a package that you need, it's also straightforward to add (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921221/570918). [Disclosure: I am on the Conda Forge R Team.]

Comment: @merv that seems to have worked and my job is now running. Thank you for your help and the additional thread you linked.